# Load an svg file without modifying webpack in react

Tags: reactjs, svg, antd

I am using create-react-app, and antd.

I have a big file `mdi.svg` containing a lot of icons I am using on another app.
I would like to import that svg file and use those icons in antd.

Is there a way to import an svg file and use it without modifying webpack ? We didn't eject our webpack, and my superior are not really ok for customizing it.

But most of the solution I found on the internet require adding a loader in the webpack.

EDIT : I `react-app-rewired` and it works great, but is it possible to load svg as a single file ? or do I have to split all the svg in different files ?

Comment: You could use `react-app-rewired` to add additional loaders for `webpack` without ejecting.

Comment: oh, thanks, will look into this

Comment: @tarzenchugh  I `react-app-rewired` and it works great, but is it possible to load svg as a single file ? or do I have to split all the svg in different files ?

Comment: You could apply different approaches, you could use compressor plugin for single svg and use that as svg sprite, or you could divide the svg into different svgs. Try this link - (http://svgsplit.com/).

Comment: I've try to use ```react-app-rewire-external-svg-loader``` but without success. Follow the steps in the git repository but it fails when svg is loaded in the html. It's empty. If you have another approach please share with us. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it fits your case, but you can import SVG like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as MySvgFile } from './my_svg_file.svg'
...
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <MySvgFile />
  )
}
```